# Deleting images from server when deleting in Ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, image, ckeditor

I am using `PHP and Ckeditor` in order to upload in MYSQL database a post with text and images.
Please, how can I delete automatically images from the uploaded folder on server  when I delete them in the WYSIWYG window of Ckeditor, or when I delete the record of a post from database? 
Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: when you delete the post from the database, and also you `unlink()` the image file from the uploads folder as long as you don't need that image somewhere else

Comment: See this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp

Comment: Please update your question with your code...what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have no idea where to start from.